# Google Maps v3 multiple markers + geolocation

Tags: javascript, google-maps, web-applications, geolocation

I'm making a web application for the university where I work. I need to plot multiple markers—for which I have lat/lon—and geolocate the user.

I've been able to do each of those tasks separately, just not on the same map.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Example of the locations: http://www.colum.edu/campusmap/

Example of the map in the app: http://colum.pixelydo.com/map.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Put the locations into a KML file.

***Note: Google Maps KML are lon, lat; not lat, lon***